# How to save back data to original json file?

Tags: json, reactjs, state, form-data, insert-update

```
    state = {one_book : []}


updateName = event =>{
        var newvalue = event.target.value
        const id = 1;
        let one_book = this.state.one_book;     // create the copy of state array
        one_book[1] = newvalue;                  //new value
        this.setState({ one_book }); 
        console.log(this.state.one_book)
    }
```

Here new value is the update value that we want to change into the json file. I want to update the bookname with id =1 with this new name or whole of the object in json file with one_book.. the changes should reflect in the original json file

```
I have to update this state into json file with the respective id.
Here is my json file
[
    {
            "id": 1,
            "bookname": "Physics",
            "price": 600,
            "author": "ABC",
            "pages": 567,
            "category" : "School Books"
    },
    {
            "id": 2,
            "bookname": "Let Us C",
            "price": 1300,
            "author": "XYZ",
            "pages": 1267,
            "category" : "Technical"  
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This `let one_book = this.state.one_book;` does not create a copy of the array. Javascript arrays and objects are stored in variables as references.

To copy the array without accidental mutation, use destructuring:

```js
let one_book = [...this.state.one_book];
```

However, it looks like you're trying to get the `id` of the book by using the array index as if it were the `id`. Instead you'll need to find the correct object by the id.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
 state = {one_book : [
    {
       "id": 1,
       "bookname": "Physics",
       "price": 600,
       "author": "ABC",
       "pages": 567,
       "category" : "School Books"
    },
    {
       "id": 2,
       "bookname": "Let Us C",
       "price": 1300,
       "author": "XYZ",
       "pages": 1267,
       "category" : "Technical"  
    }
]}


 updateName = event => {
   var newValue = event.target.value
   const id = 1;
   // Map over the array values
   let newBooks = this.state.one_book.map(book => {
      // If the id matches, update the book name
      if (book.id === id) {
       return {...book, bookname: newValue}
      }
      return book;
    })
  
    // Update the state with the new array
    this.setState({ one_book: newBooks }); 
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.one_book)
    return <input onChange={this.updateName} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hey.. thanks.But i want to add one more thing.. that  books data is in aonther json file. i want to update into that

Comment: I have updated values in this.state.books array.. everything is fine up till here.. now i want the whole json file to be replaced by this array.

Comment: I tried using this.. const fs = require('fs');
saveBook = () =>{
        let data = JSON.stringify(this.state.books);
        fs.writeFileSync('./books-details.json', data);

    }                                                                                                                          
     <button onClick={this.saveBook}>Save Book</button>

Answer (score 0):

Your logic to copy an array is incorrect.

```
updateName = event =>{
        var newvalue = event.target.value
        const id = 1;

        let one_book = [...this.state.one_book];     // create the copy of state array
        one_book[1] = newvalue;                  //new value
        this.setState({ one_book }); 
        console.log(this.state.one_book)
    }
```